# I can't view the orders on the woocomerce dashboard with the brainblocks plugin

Tags: plugins, php, errors, wp-error

I'm trying to make a website that accepts the nano cryptocurrency and I've encountered an error. 
I'm using woocomerce+brainblocks plugin and whenever I tested paying with nano it did not show up in woocomerce dashboard under orders. 
I looked at my error log and I got the following:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'brainblocks_token_query' not found or invalid function name in /home/u598547570/domains/nanoid.store/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
```

I've contacted the brainblock developers about this bug and they said they'd look into it, but I don't know how long they'll take to fix it. 
Its there any way I could fix it myself?

Comment: The `brainblocks_token_query()` function is hooked to one of the action or filter hooks (`add_action('some_hook_name', 'brainblocks_token_query')`), but no such function was found.

Comment: I've found the following in the brainblocks code:   `add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'brainblocks_token_query', 10, 2 ); `  could that that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that second line. Check if there is a function with "_brainblocks_token_query_" name. Maybe there is a typo in the name of the function, the file with this function is not included, or it is the name of the class method but added to the filter hook like a normal function. Look for the function definition (`function brainblocks_token_query`) in the plugin files.

Comment: I looked at the function and found this ` public function brainblocks_token_query( $query, $query_vars ) {
            if ( ! empty( $query_vars['_brainblocks_token'] ) ) {
                $query['meta_query'] = array(
                    'key' => '_brainblocks_token',
                    'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['_brainblocks_token'] ),
                );
            }
            return $query;
        } ` I couldn't find anything wrong with it as far as typos, but I don't know php really. Thanks for the help by the way I really appreciate it.

Comment: The "public" qualifier suggests that the function is inside some class. If `add_filter(..)` is in the same class, it should look like this `add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array($this, 'brainblocks_token_query'), 10, 2 );` or if the function that adds the filter is static: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(__CLASS__, 'brainblocks_token_query'), 10, 2 );`

Comment: Thanks, but that's didn't solve my problem.